# one function break onother. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to stop one function by another one?

I want something like this  :

```
 function foo()
 {
   bar();
   /*if is ok, then continue, else break*/
 }

 function bar()
 {
   if(!/**condition**/) stop foo();
 }
```

*I know this is possible by using something like this :*

```
  function foo()
  {
    if(!bar()) return;
  }
```

**But maybe there is a better way?**

Sample :

```
  var dk = new function() {
   this.doSomething() {
     this.em("some_id") || return;
   };

    this.em(data) { 
      return document.getElementById(data);
    };
  };
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking for **exceptions**.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using the returned value

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz what do you mean by "exceptions"?

Comment: The other possible way, but not so sane, wise, safe is using a global variable that bar() will change and foo() will check.

Comment: The way you've already suggested is the best way.

Comment: See [JavaScript exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, you could not tell the calling function to stop executing.

The second version you suggested is common practise for achieving this behaviour - let a function return `true` if it succeded and `false` if it didn't, then let the calling function decide what to do (i.e. break its execution).

Another approach might be throwing an exception. You should consider yourself what might be more useful in your situation

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered yourself..

`bar()` function could make all the checks or code you want then it return `true` or `false` to the calling function `foo()`

based on the returned value you decide either to continue your code execution or stopping it.